# Can I use a S3 bucket object as a push notification (Polling object) without any issues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, polling

Background :  Due to quick development we have our servers in PHP and implementing services like `Pusher` and `Socket.io` is not an option.

So, we are planning on using `AWS S3 bucket` files and the data content, to **update** them and  to **poll** them and  see if there are new messages or not.

Would like to know how many requests/second can an S3 file or an S3 Bucket handle ?

Comment: You can make pretty much as many requests per second as you want, but beware your bill at the end of the month as you are charged per API call.

Comment: Sorry I'm not to familiar with the use case you're describing so could be completely misunderstanding but have you considered SQS? It sounds like a perfect fit. One issue that could be an issue using S3 like this is the eventual consistency model it uses.

Comment: Who's updating S3? (your server?) and who's polling S3? (the users' browsers)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Yep, Server is updating, Browser's, mobile are polling.

Comment: @Mike : Not exactly, what I am looking for, even though it seems a theoretically correct approach . But right now we are developing a quick prototype and avoiding research time :-(

Comment: @Finch_Powers : Please write it as an answer, if you are sure, I shall mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make pretty much as many requests per second as you want, but beware your bill at the end of the month as you are charged per API call.

Further more, depending on the region you are using there may be no "read after write consistency", which could make your application unreliable.

Bottom line: can you do it? Yes. Do I recommend it? Considering your use case: no.